# How to ignore index files of MapFiles when running MR jobs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a directory full of `MapFile`s. I now want to run a MR Job on them. I use the `SequenceFileInputFormat` of the new API which should be aware of `MapFile`s as one answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753470/mapfile-as-a-input-to-a-mapreduce-job) states. But however, this does not work. The job runs up to a certain percentage and after that, I get

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to com.mycompany.MyOwnWritable
```

I suppose the mapper trips over the index file. How can I make sure these are ignored, or better, only files which have the correct input key and value classes are used? The only way that comes to mind is overriding `Mapper<Object, Object, MyKeyOut, MyValueOut>` and using `if`s and `instanceof` checks, but I consider this ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where it trips over the index files. When enabling recursive traversal of the input paths (by setting `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` to `true`) the files for the map tasks are gathered by walking down the file and directory tree. The `SequenceFileInputFormat` then receives the individual files instead of the directories and thus, the `MapFile` detection fails. It only works if the input format receives the **directory** containing the two files composing the `MapFile`.
When turning off recursion and ensuring the layout MR expects - i.e., a directory where all `MapFile`s to be processed are stored "flat" without an additional folder structure - or adding all directories containing `MapFile`s manually by calling `FileInputFormat.addInputPath` for every such directory, the job runs without failing.

EDIT: Reported as a bug: [MAPREDUCE-6155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-6155)